# Is there a way to see tags that have no wiki?

Tags: support

Tags are often more useful with WIKIs attached. Is there  a way to see only the tags that are not defined?

Answer (score 5):

Here [is a query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stats/query/82928/tags-with-no-wiki) that produces tags with no wiki from the Stack Exchange data dump. These are sorted descendingly by the number of questions that have that tag, hence tags that need wiki's and are used the most. I include the length as a potential indicator that a wiki, even if it has some text, can be potentially expanded upon.

Unfortunately the data dump can not keep up with your recent work! But hopefully this is useful enough to see potential candidates.

Note that a tag wiki and a tag wiki excerpt are different, and you can have wiki excerpt without a full tag wiki (it appears all tags with wiki's have an excerpt, I assume this is by design). Included in the query are the tag wiki excerpts, so you can filter them out as well. I include length so one can also see short wiki's that are potentially candidates to be expanded upon.

Answer (score 3):

I appreciate the work you've been doing making sure that tags have at least a wiki excerpt.  I agree that that makes them more useful.

One way to see which tags don't have wiki's is to click on the gray [TAGS](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags) button at the top of the page.  You can see the top 36 most used tags ever on CV; you can also sort alphabetically or by recently added.  Below the tags a portion of the wiki excerpt is displayed.  On the first page, all the tags have wiki's, but those are also the most important to have wiki's.  If you keep going through the pages to less frequently used tags, you will start to see some that don't have a wiki excerpt. At the time of this writing, 'experiment-design' is the most frequently used tag without a wiki excerpt; it's on the second page.

I don't know of a way to determine which tags don't have full wiki's, other than clicking on them & navigating to it, but I also think the full wiki's are less important than the wiki excerpts.

Comment: Hi @gung. Thanks. But what I wanted was a filter that identified all the un-wikied tags.

Comment: I don't know of one. There may well be a way via the SE data site. I believe it uses MS SQL server, if you know that.